Suspending and Resuming Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen 10 in Debian 12
S3 suspend used to work on this machine, but then I updated the firmware and now it doesn't.
systemctl suspend makes the screen go black and print

Allocating and mlocking memory: 1050624 kb
Sleeping ...

And that's it. It just hangs there.
I updated the firmware to fix a different, but probably worse bug where the system would not boot if a usb device was inserted.
What I've done to try to fix it:

Reinstall firmware via gnome-firmware
Upgrade to kernel 6.7 (from bookworm-backports).
Use S0 sleep instead of S3 (which worked before).

Help will be much appreciated! I travel a lot and sleep mode is very convenient!
Update:
I got it working. See answer below.

Have you updated UEFI?

Thanks for the comment! Do you mean the UEFI firmware? I did update those. I also made a few other changes to my UEFI settings during the maintenance that preceded this issue. Could something like cause this?

Yes, that's what I meant. And maybe you need to try other settings.

The UEFI suspend setting is set for Linux S3.

Your "updated 2" shouldn't be in the question but in answer :)

I got it working eventually.  The root cause was actually the autorandr.service which was triggered by sleep.target.wants. Autorandr was running during suspend and causing all sorts of problems and was badly interacting with cryptsetup-suspend. Yet autorandr is meant to run only during wake-up. The solution was to remove this dependency and to trigger autorandr to run after sleep.
I linked the issue to the cryptsetup-suspend package by checking journalctl -b-1 after setting LogLevel info in /etc/systemd/system.conf. There I saw an infinite loop of errors related to cryptsetup. I had recently install cryptsetup-suspend and so I uninstalled it. Then with iam_tj in matrix linked it to autorandr and helped me find the solutuion. A possible related cause (or separate issue) was related to my updated firmware and linux kernel 6.1. I eventually got my system into a satisfactory state, with acceptable battery retention during sleep via these steps:

Upgrade linux kernel from 6.1 to 6.7
Configure Bios Sleep mode to Windows / Linux (this corresponds to S0).
Check that /sys/power/proc_sleep contains "s2idle".
Edit autorandr.service and remove the [Install] section
Add a script to /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep that executes /usr/bin/autorandr --batch --change --default default. With this setup cryptsetup-suspend will work with "s2idle".

I tested that this configuration effectively saves power. I observed minimal battery drain in 1.5h.
